# Remove index.php for subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain

Current page is with subdomain.(bla.examplewebsite.com)
I trying to remove the index.php with official document(http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/urls/remove_index.php.html) way, but it seem like doesn't work. Can anyone help?

Comment: what server you use? nginx/apache?

Comment: @MaxLazar apache

Comment: Can you include an example of you htaccess that you are trying to do this with?

Comment: Are you sure isn't a matter of required query strings? `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]`?

Comment: no httpS? I'm asking because htaccess for domain or subdomain is usually no difference. Question is if your htaccess rule overwrite is applied to your subdomain at all. Try to add deny rule into your subdomain htaccess and check if it effected on subdomain site.